# How do you import tags from EE (solspace tags) along with entries?

Tags: plugins, import

Has anyone successfully imported tags from EE (solspace tags) along with entries? I installed [this plugin](http://straightupcraft.com/craft-plugins/ee-craft-import) but it seems to be really old and Craft must have changed a lot since then since it reflects even a different Schema and many deprecated methods. I refactored to work with simple entry fields but importing tags along with that seems a little trickier.

I think I am good if I can just figure out how to save relations for entries. VERY new to craft as in 2 days but this all seems familiar since I'm a Laravel guy.

[image]

I can figure this stuff out by following the trails but if someone else has tackled this or can give me quick feedback on using the services and models that would so super fantastical.

Answer (score 1):

I would use the "[Feed Me](https://github.com/engram-design/FeedMe)" plugin which allows to import entries including tags from feeds (XML, RSS, Atom). So you only have to create an XML feed with all the information you want to transfer (which is in EE quite easy).